# Is it possible to get hdparm to report the current level of performance degradation on my SSD?

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, ssd, hdparm

I work on a product that is a headless Debian Linux system with removable Intel X-25M solid state drives.  Recently we noticed that the read/write performance of these drives degrades over time, and sure enough the culprit was SSD block problems, as described [here](http://thessdreview.com/ssd-guides/optimization-guides/ssd-performance-loss-and-its-solution/).  So we did a secure erase of the SSD drive (as described [here](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/t/a/ATA_Secure_Erase_936d.html)) and the SSD drives' performance is restored to its original/factory level.

Which is great, but what I'm wondering now is if there is some quick-and-easy way to query hdparm (or some other Linux shell command) so it will print out an indication of how badly degraded the SSD's block-structure currently is.  If so, then I could add some logic to my own program to automatically notify the user when a secure-erase would significantly improve his system's performance.  As it is, the user just has to sort of guess based on observed I/O performance compared to what it was previously... which isn't the end of the world, but it would be nicer if he just got a warning message "your data SSD is currently 35% scrambled, consider doing a secure-erase to get better SSD performance", or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you dig through SMART indicators for harddrive.

```
smartctl -data -A /dev/sda
```

It will definitely give you indicators

Again, have considered SSD optimization tweaks in linux

[SSD TWEAKS FOR LINUX](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/geek-sheet-a-tweakers-guide-to-solid-state-drives-ssds-and-linux/9190)

Comment: you can install smartctl with "apt-get install smartmontools"